# Magento Use jQuery to populate form fields in admin panel

Tags: jquery, forms, magento, magento-1.7

I'm new to magento and I'm creating an eshop now. I want to add some jquery code to prepopulate some fields I want. For example I want when adding a new Product Category to auto choose "isAnchor" = true  and active = true. Also I want when adding a new product to auto choose a certain tax selection and prepopulate some other fields with some values I want as default.

Can some one suggest on where should I put my code in each case to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide code example or link the page

Comment: You should create your custom JS and load it into your layout

Comment: @FrancisKim My question is Magento generic. No need to provide any Link. Thank you.

Comment: @medina Did you read my question? You answer my question witha part of it. As I said above, I want to add some jquery code ...   Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1>>** Download jquery and save it to **js/jquery** directory

**Step 3>>** create a new js file **js/custom/autoPopulate.js** and add below content.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   alert('succeed!!'); 
});
```

**Step 2>>** Create **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml**

**Step 3>>** Add below code to the above created file

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>js</type>
            <!-- Jquery file path here-->
                <name>jquery/JQUERY_FILE_NAME.js</name>
            </action>
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>js</type>
                <name>custom/autoPopulate.js</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

After above steps, go to catalog>>product>>edit section and see it alerts "succeed!!". If it does, write your code in auoPopulate.js. Be careful, magento loads some data using ajax, better to wait to complete the ajax request before executing your code, otherwise it may throw errors

Comment: I managed to show the succedded message. I actually changed it to: <adminhtml_catalog_product_new> because I want the autopopulate only on new products. But now everything else breaks. The page does not load the fields. The menu is disabled and I can only go to Dashboard. Etc. Any suggestions? How can I make it work only after everything has loaded?

Comment: @panos check your browser console, whether you can see any js errors?

Comment: jQuery has some conflicts in Magento so jquery "noConflict" must be used. What I wanted to do was quite trivial ( change the value of "Enabled" select box ) so I used traditional javascript and it worked fine. My problem is when I want to do this in categories where they are created using ajax and I can't run my methods on ajax callback.

Comment: What about creating a module and observing to product creation event on magento? There you can set some default values including product attributes and categories!!